# Outliers handling

Tags: python, outlier

I have a large dataset of >100 columns with nearly all types of data.
I want to remove outliers from my dataset for which purpose I've decided to use IQR.
Problem is even when I apply quantile of 0.25/0.75, I still get significant amount of outliers in columns like ClientTotalIncome, etc. Further by doing that, I eliminate more than 90% data.
My code in  Python for outliers removal is as follows:

```
num_train = train.select_dtypes(include=['number'])
cat_train = train.select_dtypes(exclude=['number'])
Q1 = num_train.quantile(0.25)
Q3 = num_train.quantile(0.75)
IQR = Q3 - Q1
idx = ~((num_train < (Q1 - 1.5 * IQR)) | (num_train > (Q3 + 1.5 * 
IQR))).any(axis=1)
train_cleaned = pd.concat([num_train.loc[idx], cat_train.loc[idx]], axis=1)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not always a good idea to remove data from your dataset.

In some circumstances - and income is a good example - your data will be skewed / long-tailed and so will lie outside of the interquartile range. This doesn't imply that there is anything wrong with the data, but rather that there is a disparity between observations.

Nevertheless, if you are set on removing observations perhaps you should consider scaling your features prior to determining which observations are outliers. For example, taking the `log` of a feature and then applying your outlier removal based on the `log(variable)`.

Don't forget that IQR doesn't carry over well to categorical and ordered features.